# MST challenge gives "time exceeded" error

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, priority-queue, minimum-spanning-tree

I am doing the [BLINNET problem on *Sphere Online Judge*](https://www.spoj.com/problems/BLINNET/) where I need to find the cost of a minimum spanning tree. I should follow a structure with `Edge` and `Vertex` instances. Vertices represent cities in this case.

I get a "time exceeded" error, and I feel like too many `for` loop iterations are at the cause, but that is the best I can do. I want to try the binary sort to see if it works with that, but that is not easy as it should be sorted using the `key` property in the `City` class.

#### Sample input

```
2

4
gdansk
2
2 1
3 3
bydgoszcz
3
1 1
3 1
4 4
torun
3
1 3
2 1
4 1
warszawa
2
2 4
3 1

3
ixowo
2
2 1
3 3
iyekowo
2
1 1
3 7
zetowo
2
1 3
2 7
```

#### Output for the Sample

```
3
4
```

### My code

```
import sys
import heapq

class City:

    def __init__(self, city_id):
        self.city_id = city_id
        self.key = float('inf')
        self.parent = None
        self.edge_list = list()
        self.visited = False
        #self.city_name = None

    def is_not_visited(self):
        if self.visited is False:
            return True
        return False

    def add_neighbor(self, edge):
        self.edge_list.append(edge)

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.key < other.key

class Edge:

    def __init__(self, to_vertex, cost):
        self.to_vertex = to_vertex
        self.cost = cost

#
# def find_and_pop(queue):
#     min = queue[0]
#     index = 0
#     for a in range(0, len(queue)):
#         if queue[a].key < min.key:
#             min = queue[a]
#             index = a
#     return queue.pop(index)
#

def MST(vertices_list):
    queue = vertices_list
    current = queue[0]
    current.key = 0
    #visited_list = list()
    #heapq.heapify(queue)
    total_weight = 0
    while queue:
        #current = find_and_pop(queue)
        current = queue.pop(0)
        for edge in current.edge_list:
            if edge.to_vertex.is_not_visited():
                if edge.cost < edge.to_vertex.key:
                    edge.to_vertex.key = edge.cost
                    edge.to_vertex.parent = current
        total_weight = total_weight + current.key
        current.visited = True
        queue = sorted(queue, key=lambda x: x.city_id)
        #heapq.heapify(queue)
        #visited_list.append(current)

    # total_weight = 0
    # for x in visited_list:
    #     total_weight = total_weight + x.key
    sys.stdout.write("{0}\n".format(total_weight))

class TestCase:
    def __init__(self, vertices):
        self.vertices = vertices

testcases = []

def main():

    case_num = int(sys.stdin.readline())
    #skip_line = sys.stdin.readline()
    for n_case in range(0, case_num):
        sys.stdin.readline()
        vertices_list = list()
        number_of_city = int(sys.stdin.readline())
        #interate and make for the time of number of cities
        for n_city in range(0, number_of_city):
            city = City(n_city)
            vertices_list.append(city)

        for n_city in range(0, number_of_city):
            c_name = sys.stdin.readline()
            #vertices_list[n_city].city_name = c_name
            num_neighbor = int(sys.stdin.readline())
            for n_neigh in range(0, num_neighbor):
                to_city_cost = sys.stdin.readline()
                to_city_cost = to_city_cost.split(" ")
                to_city = int(to_city_cost[0])
                cost = int(to_city_cost[1])
                edge = Edge(vertices_list[to_city-1], cost)
                vertices_list[n_city].edge_list.append(edge)

        testcase = TestCase(vertices_list)
        testcases.append(testcase)

    count = 0
    for testcase in testcases:
        MST(testcase.vertices)
        # if count < case_num -1:
        #     print()
        # count = count + 1



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Tip: search for minimal spanning tree.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I am doing MST as you see that, updating the key values if the vertex is not visited. Total_weight is only for output. But, I am getting time exceeded errors and I don't know what is causing that.

Comment: Which algorithm are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sorted` call in your MST loop makes the solution inefficient. You have some commented-out code that relies on `heapq`, and that is indeed the way to avoid having to sort the queue each time you alter it. Anyway, I don't understand why you would sort the queue by city id. If anything, it should be sorted by `key`.

Although it could work with the `key` property as you did it, it seems more natural to me to add *edges* to the queue (heap) instead of vertices, so you have the edge cost as the basis for the heap property. Also, that queue should not have all the items from the start, but add them as they are selected during the algorithm. And, that corresponds more the the MST-building algorithm, which adds edge after edge, each time the one with the minimum cost.

If edges are pushed on a heap, they must be comparable. So `__lt__` must be implemented on the Edge class like you did for the Vertex class.

```
class Edge:
    # ... your code remains unchanged... Just add:
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.cost < other.cost

def MST(vertices_list):
    # first edge in the queue is a virtual one with zero cost.
    queue = [Edge(vertices_list[0], 0)] # heap of edges, ordered by cost
    total_weight = 0
    while queue:
        mst_edge = heapq.heappop(queue) # pop both cost & vertex
        current = mst_edge.to_vertex
        if current.visited: continue
        for edge in current.edge_list:
            if not edge.to_vertex.visited:
                heapq.heappush(queue, edge)
        current.visited = True
        total_weight += mst_edge.cost

    sys.stdout.write("{0}\n".format(total_weight))
```

Comment: sorting by a key value was a mistake but I will try with yours. Thank you very much for answering despite a poor question

Comment: Why returning 0 in __lt__?
And  "heapq.heappush(queue, (path_weight + edge.cost, edge))" I don't get this part. Path_weight might be the key, which is the cost from the source and edge.cost might mean the cost of the vertex right?

Comment: Now I am getting wrong answer even I get the right answer of 3 and 4. I think I need more examples to play with but they don't provide another example.

Comment: I updated my answer, as the thing about minimal path was not correct: it is the edge with minimum cost that needs to be added. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Perfect now it works but I need sometime to compare your code and my code. Cuz it seems like the logic is almost identical but you code is working. Thank you